# Where can I upload data permanently?

Tags: file-upload, upload

assume I have some thesis etc. and want to give the audience the possibility to download the coding part and test it;
Is there a platform for professionally upload it and also keep it there permanently (of course it should not be deleted within a couple of months)

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Yeah, Github sounds like the place to go at the moment. (This is not on topic here, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools such as Git-hub or bitbucket. These allow you to upload code and even have version control. Users can download your code directly and use it if they need to.